# Why isn't the text inside the div?

Tags: html, css

I just began to play around with HTML/CSS and I'm already stuck.

I tried to google my problem but I think I'm missing some keywords to find a solution. Why isn't the Link and Text inside `<div id="NavContent>`?

[DEMO](http://scrare.de/)

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav {
    background-color: #2a9dfc;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}

#NavContent {
    border: 2px solid black;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#Link {
    float:left;
}

#Text {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>scrare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="NavContent">
            <a id="Link" href="/">Link</a>
            <div id="Text">Text</div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you set elements inside a div as float, they lost their influence on height attribute on parent element.

That said, you can:

- Set a height for the div; or
- Add a empty `<div>` after `<div id="text">` but not inside, with `style='clear: both;'`

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is to add `overflow: hidden;` to `#NavContent`.

Or you can add the `clearfix` solution -

```
#NavContent:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
body {
margin:0;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav {
background-color: #2a9dfc;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 13px;
padding-bottom: 13px;
}

#NavContent {
border: 2px solid black;
max-width: 900px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#Link {
float:left;
}

#Text {
float:right;
}
#NavContent:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <div id="NavContent">
  <a id="Link" href="/">Link
  </a>
  <div id="Text">
     Text
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<main>
</main>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to solve your problem.

- Add a suitable height to `#NavContent` element (like `height:200px`)

  Or
- set overflow property of `#NavContent` to `auto`